# Use select in PHP, MySQL when I know exactly which column i need

Tags: php, mysql, select

now i use this code:

```
$welcome_text = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE `name` = 'welcome'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($welcome_text, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 echo $row['content'];
}
```

Is it possible to use it without WHILE if i know exactly which one column i need?
Something like this:

```
$welcome_text = mysql_query("SELECT 'content' FROM `text` WHERE `name` = 'welcome'");
echo $welcome_text;
```

Thanks

Comment: You are thinking right way. All repetitive actions should be shortened. Though you can't use native functions that way but you can create your own one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_query` makes the query, returns a result set.

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches the first row from the result set.

```
$welcome_text = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE `name` = 'welcome'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($welcome_text, MYSQL_ASSOC);
echo $row['content'];
```

Of course, you can shorten your code if you want, but this may make your code more difficult to debug and maintain.

Verbose, clear code > one-liner 'show-off' code.

Including 'just-in-case' checking:

```
$welcome_text = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `text` WHERE `name` = 'welcome'");
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($welcome_text, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['content'];
}
```

Good practice to make doubly sure you have what you need before printing it.

Finally, please make sure you sanitize user-submitted data *before* it goes into your database. If you're not going to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), at least use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

**Practice safe SQL**, wear a prepared statement to prevent [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Actually there is nothing to sanitize. Save for numbers probably. Strings are already all right, *if treated properly.* And such a treatment is much more important to mention

Comment: @TheColonel: Excuse my ignorance, what do you mean by 'treated properly'?

Answer (score 3):

I would write a function for this:

```
// Returns content of first column in first result and 
// returns null if query returns no records
function mysql_get_result($sql) {

   $query = mysql_query($sql); // you may add error handling ...
   if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM));         
      return $row[0];
   } else {
      return null;
   }
}
```

And now you can use:

```
$welcome_text = mysql_get_result("SELECT `content` FROM `text` WHERE `name` = 'welcome'");
```

**Note:** You may throw an exception instead of returning the `null` value. But what is better is hard to say and it may depend on your programming style.

Comment: I'd throw an exception only if query returns false. While such a business logic issue I'd handle in the same business logic way, not error handling way. But yes, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

That's not entirely the same thing. In your first sample, you're iterating over multiple *rows*, not columns.

Unless you're certain that there's only one row with the name `welcome`, you're still going to need the loop.

You are right that you shouldn't `select *` when you only need  some of the columns, it's wasteful.

In other words, you should use the only slightly modified:

```
$welcome_text = mysql_query("SELECT `content` FROM `text` WHERE `name` = 'welcome'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($welcome_text, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['content'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$welcome_text = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT 'content' FROM `text` WHERE `name` = 'welcome'"));
echo $welcome_text[0];
```

Comment: Never try to stuff all your code into one line, son. It's silly.

Comment: Well, isn't that what the OP was kind of asking for? Doesn't mean that it's a good idea.

Comment: @EboMike don't have the OP's code as an excuse :) They **are** asking because they don't know the right way. So, do not follow their mind, but propose something better.